# How can I use yield with Slick Query?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

How can I use yield with [Slick Query](http://slick.typesafe.com/) ? So imagine I have code like this

```
def rolesQuery(owner_id: UUID) = for {
  (role, rel) <- Roles innerJoin AbilitiesMapping on (_.id === _.obj_id) if rel.owner_id === owner_id.bind
} yield role
```

which I use like this

```
val rolesQuery: lifted.Query[Roles.type, Role] = DBManager.rolesQuery(user_id)
rolesQuery.foreach((role: Role) => {
  println(modifiedRole(role))
})
```

but what if I want to produce another container with modified Roles ? I tried this

```
val lst = for (role <- rolesQuery)
  yield modifiedRole(role)
```

But it returns [WrappingQuery](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/api/#scala.slick.lifted.WrappingQuery) in `lst` instead of actually case class object. I see that there is `mapResults` method but it returns object of type [UnitInvoker](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.UnitInvoker) instead of container of `Role`-s

What should I do ? Shall I just call `.list()` on Query object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you if you want to process the results in a for comprehension, you will need to fetch the data and `list` will accomplish that.  As it stands, your for-comp seems to be just mapping from one query to another query:

```
val lst = for (role <- rolesQuery.list)
  yield modifiedRole(role)
```

Just make sure you have an implicit `Session` in scope.